# How to get the sqrt symbol in a buttons value?

Tags: css, html, button, sqrt

im trying to get the sqrt symbol to display inside my button. I cant seem to get it to work. Here is my button code

```
<input type="button" id="sqrt" value="sqrt" onclick="insert function here">
```

We the value, i need to get the sqrt symbol to show up and I cant seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to find a specific symbol you can refer to [W3's Character Entity Reference Chart](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).

The [Square Root (√) symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221a/index.htm) can be displayed using one of the following:

```
&radic;
&Sqrt;
&#x0221A;
&#8730;
```

For example:

```
<input type="button" value="&radic;" />       <!-- or... -->
<input type="button" value="&Sqrt;" />        <!-- or... -->
<input type="button" value="&#x0221A;" />     <!-- or... -->
<input type="button" value="&#8730;" />
```

Personally I'd opt for either `&#x0221A;` or `&#8730;` as these directly reference the symbol's Unicode ID. A browser may not necessarily have any mapping defined for `&radic;` or `&Sqrt;`.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HkbnU/).

Answer (score 2):

Use `&radic;`:

```
<input class="sqrt-input" type="submit" value="&radic;" />
```

Change the font if you don't like the default look:

```
/* If find Verdana pretty good for this and it's available 
on almost every browser. */
.sqrt-input {
    font-family: Verdana; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use the character itself:

```
<input type="button" id="sqrt" value="√" onclick="...">
```

You then need to make sure that the character encoding is utf-8 and this is declared in HTTP headers, but you should do that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use an img tag inside a button tag like this :-

```
<button TYPE="submit" >
<img src="" >
</button>
```

Here put the path of your image in the src attribute. You can also add hieght and width properties to define size for your button and attributes like align="absmiddle" to position image in middle of the button.

for example

```
<button TYPE="submit" >
<img style="height:25px;width:65px;" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_0agwm6I7YZE/TO_DccbrDBI/AAAAAAAAMEU/0OADo56Xqxw/s1600/square-root.jpg" align="absmiddle" >
</button>
```